# What is the difference between using window.onload() and normally calling a function in a JS file?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want the console to write "Hello World" when my page loads.

I would do something like this:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

But what is the difference between doing that and simply calling window.onload()?

```
window.onload = function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

In both of these cases, the console displays "Hello World" upon the page load.
What is the difference?

Comment: Um, if you put that first snippet in a script in your header, it's *not* executed upon the page load (`load` event fires after the page finished loading). Of course, it's executed *during* the load, while the browser is loading the page.

Comment: Did you mean head instead of header?

Comment: Yeah, `<head>` element, all things that are not at the end of the document, whatever. Not the HTTP headers for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing **only** with `console.log("Hello World")`, it makes **NO** difference.

But consider the following situation.

```
var element = document.getElementById('myid');
alert(element.innerHTML);
```

If this code is executed before the HTML is even rendered, then it won't find any element having `id='myid'`.

That's why `window.onload()` is used which forces the execution of JavaScript only after the HTML content is completely rendered.

Comment: Thanks, but If I put my script at the bottom of the <body> tag, that means that that script is executed after the body is rendered. Right? So I don't need to use     window.onload() if my script is in the <body> .

Comment: Right. Because `HTML` is parsed, **NOT** compiled. So it will render from `Top to Bottom` which will allow the JavaScript to execute only after the entire `body` is loaded.